# I am facing a glTextureStorage2D error. Opengl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, graphics, textures

Here is an image of the issue I am facing in opengl:

[image: glTextureStorage2D ERROR]

In the image I tagged my texture also displays weirdly.
Can someone help me figure out why the texture on the ground is incomplete and placed odd?

This is my code:

```
 Ground.LoadModel("O_Ground.obj");
            Fence.LoadModel("O_Fence.obj");

            string names[] = { "Green.jpg","wood.jpg" };
            glGenTextures(2, texture);
            for( string name :names)
            { 
            stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
            int iWidth, iHeight, iChannels;
            unsigned char* iData = stbi_load(name.c_str(), &iWidth, &iHeight, &iChannels, 0);
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
             { 
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]); 
            glTextureStorage2D(texture[i], 1, GL_RGB8, iWidth, iHeight);
            glTextureSubImage2D(texture[i], 0, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, iData);
            cout << texture[i];
             
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

             }
            }
```

This is my render function

```
    for (int i = 0;i < 2; i++)

    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
        GLint tex_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture[i]");
        glUniform1i(tex_location, i);
    }
    
    Ground.Draw();
    Fence.Draw();
```

And my vertex and fragment shaders

vsmodel1

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 tc;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normals;

out VS_OUT
{
    vec2 tc;
    vec3 normals;
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    vs_out.tc = tc;
    vs_out.normals = normals;
}
```

fsmodel1

```
out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT
{
    vec2 tc;
    vec3 normals;
} 

fs_in;


layout(binding=0)uniform sampler2D tex;
  

void main(void)
{
color= texture(tex, fs_in.tc);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The functions `glTextureStorage2D` and `glTextureSubImage2D` are **not** part of OpenGL 4.3 which you are using here.

These functions were introduced with [*direct state access*](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) in OpenGL 4.5. You'll have to use the non-DSA functions `glTexStorage2D` and `glTexSubImage2D` instead, with the other semantics of course.

This part of the code is also not going to work:

> ```
> for (int i = 0;i < 2; i++)
>
> {
>     glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
>     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
>     GLint tex_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture[i]");
>     glUniform1i(tex_location, i);
> }
> ```

There is no uniform called `texture` in your shader program. And even if it were, and it were an array, `texture[i]` would still not work, as the `i` is just part of the string literal, and not the value of the variable `i` you declared in your code.

Since the above `glGetUniformLocation()` calls a guaranteed to return `-1`, thew `glUniform` call following it will have no effect.

Your shader:

> ```
> // [...]
> layout(binding=0)uniform sampler2D tex;
>   
>
> void main(void)
> {
>     color= texture(tex, fs_in.tc);
> }
> ```

is only using a `tex` uniform, and it is using *only one texture unit* at all. The `tex` uniform will point to unit 0. It is totally unclear why you even bind 2 different textures at once to units 0 and 1, if your shader can ever only deal with one.

Comment: I have an array GLuint texture[3]. Could you help me by editing my code for me I find what you said a little hard to understand. I am a beginner and this is or an assignment. It would really mean a lot if you could edit the changes so I could get those two textures on my two objects. please? I'm honestly helpless at this point. It would help me a lot if you edited them. and thank you for explaining  this to me. I've been trying for days to get a response.

Comment: No, I'm not doing your homework for you. The problem here is that you're lacking some of the very basic and central concepts of OpenGL and shader programming, and teaching all of this is completely outside the scope of this site. There are lots of OpenGL introductory materials and tutorials out there, like https://learnopengl.com

Comment: Its just a part of like 10 things we have to do, you didn't have to be rude. i'm short on time but oh well. thanks for responding anyways. Wish I could get more help on here.

Comment: I can only  find examples with coloring one mesh object and using one shader everywhere and I have multiple.

Comment: I didn't intend to be rude. I'm trying to help you - but not by doing your assignments for you, sorry. I don't see how your task would involve having more than one shader. However, it is totally unclear what exactly you are doing, as the code posted so far does not relate to multiple meshes at all. However, the actual _question_ you posted I did answer correctly: The issue you're facing in this question was that you call functions which are not available on your GPU. And I told you which functions you can use instead. If you have further issues, you should open individual questions for each.